# Rails 5: Ways to validate forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on a form:

```
 <%= form_for(@contact, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>

      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h2 class="display-5 main-text-blue text-center font-weight-bold">Add New Contact</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">

     <div class="errors">
                <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                       <h5 class="text-center mb-n1 pb-1"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle text-danger"></i> Please correct the following errors: </h5>
                   </div>
                <% end %>
            </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mx-auto">

            <div class="wrap" id="avatar-container">
                  <div class="valign-middle">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <% if @contact.new_record? %>
                             <%= image_tag "100x100.png", class: "img-responsve img-preview" %>
                          <% else %>
                              <%= image_tag @contact.avatar, class: "img-responsve img-preview" %>
                             <% end %>
                          <label for="file" class="sr-only">Choose Image</label>
                           <%= f.file_field :contact_avatar, id: "file" %>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :name, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %> 
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :name) }", id: "name", placeholder: "Name.." %>
                <% if has_error?(@contact, :name) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@contact, :name)%>
                      </span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
             <%= f.label :email, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %> 
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <%= f.text_field :email, class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :email) }", id: "email", placeholder: "Email.." %>
             <% if has_error?(@contact, :email) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@contact, :email)%>
                      </span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :mobile, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %> 
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <%= f.text_field :mobile, class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :mobile) }", id: "mobile", placeholder: "Mobile.." %>
              <% if has_error?(@contact, :mobile) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@contact, :mobile)%>
                      </span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
             <%= f.label :phone, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %> 
            <div class="col-lg-10">
             <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :phone) }", id: "phone", placeholder: "Phone.." %>
              <% if has_error?(@contact, :phone) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@contact, :phone)%>
                      </span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :country, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
               <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control", id: "country", placeholder: "Country.." %>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :address, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control", id: "address", placeholder: "Address.." %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-row">
             <%= f.label :location, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-4">
             <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control", id: "city", placeholder: "City.." %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
              <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control", id: "state", placeholder: "State.." %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control", id: "zip", placeholder: "Zip.." %>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row category-mt">
             <%= f.label :category, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Category" }, id: "category_select", class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :category) }" %>
                 <% if has_error?(@contact, :category) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@contact, :category)%>
                      </span>
                <% end %>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-category-button btn-block mt-1" href="#" id="add-category-btn">Add Category</a>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row" id="add-new-category">
            <label class="col-lg-2 col-form-label" for="location">New Category:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
              <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="new-category" name="new-category" class="form-control <%= 'is-invalid' if has_error?(@category, :name)  %>"  placeholder="Enter category name" type="text">
                     <% if has_error?(@category, :name) %>
                      <span class="text-danger">
                          <%= get_error(@category, :name)%>
                      </span>
                    <% end %>


                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary category-btn" id="save-new-category-btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group row">
              <%= f.label :note, class: "col-lg-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-lg-10">
               <%= f.text_area :note, class: "form-control", id: "note", placeholder: "Note..", rows: "3" %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
           <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary border-button mb-3 ml-3", id: "save-btn" %>
           <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary border-button mt-n3" data-dismiss="modal" href="#" id="cancel-btn">Cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>

       <% end %>
```

As you can see here I place some rails validation codes which already exist on contacts model. For instance:

```
<%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control #{'is-invalid' if has_error?(@contact, :name) }", id: "name", placeholder: "name.." %>
```

Which will add the class `is-invalid` if there are any errors. And this also:

```
<% if has_error?(@contact, :phone) %>
<span class="text-danger">
<%= get_error(@contact, :phone)%>
</span>
<% end %>
```

Which will simply print the error text at the bottom if there's an error. Here's the helper codes for that:

```
def has_error?(resource, field)
     resource.errors.messages[field].present?
  end

  def get_error(resource, field)
    msg = resource.errors.messages[field]
    field.to_s.capitalize + " " + msg.join(' and ') + '.'
  end
```

So, basically I am working on two tables here: Contact and Category. So far what am I verifying on my form are mostly contacts. I have this feature here where in user can add NEW CATEGORY right on the spot via ajax which is a foreign key on the contacts table which can also be seen on the code above.

[image]

Now, on my understanding, I can also add a validation on models. So I tried to put some validation on my category:

```
 validates :name, uniqueness: true
```

I was hoping that this will validate the uniqueness of the new category being output, meaning if the text (category name) already exist on the database it must prohibit it and throw an error. So what I did is I tried the following code to display the error:

```
<input id="new-category" name="new-category" class="form-control <%= 'is-invalid' if has_error?(@category, :name)  %>"  placeholder="Enter category name" type="text">
<% if has_error?(@category, :name) %>
<span class="text-danger">
 <%= get_error(@category, :name)%>
</span>
<% end %>
```

And so I thought it will work however it just throw an error saying
`undefined method errors' for nil:NilClass` which is I thought it should work since I am using `@category` but then I realize it's a form for `@contact`.

Is there a better way to make this work and display the error on the add new category field? I am really stuck on this. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get categories errors through `f` object

```
<% f.object.categories.each do |category| %>
  <input id="new-category" name="new-category" class="form-control <%= 'is-invalid' if has_error?(category, :name)  %>"  placeholder="Enter category name" type="text">
  <% if has_error?(category, :name) %>
    <span class="text-danger">
      <%= get_error(category, :name)%>
    </span>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: undefined method `categories' for #<Contact:0x00007fd36c3eaa70>

Comment: Do you have association `has_many :categories` on `Contact` model ???